# Dealing with abrupt connection losses and SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, weblogic, connection-pooling

Dealing with abrupt connection losses and `SELECT FOR UPDATE`

Consider this scenario: 
a server-side app deployed to a cluster of application servers often issues `SELECT FOR UPDATE` queries, updates data and commits transactions.
So at some point in time there are locked records (between `SFU` and the end of the current transaction).
Suppose before a transaction is committed a server node goes down or a connection is lost for any reason.
In this case a database session associated with this connection will stay open and a transaction will be active, possibly indefinitely, with those locks in place.
This will block all other transactions which later try to update at least one of the locked records, breaking the application.

Is this a valid concern?

And if yes, can I prevent it by the following?

On Oracle side:

1. use `ALTER PROFILE` to create a profile with `IDLE_TIME` of say 1 min
2. assign this profile to the user which is used by the Java
   application to connect to Oracle db

On Java side configure connection pools as this (this example if for Tomcat's pool, but Weblogic and others have their equivalents):

1. set `testWhileIdle=true`
2. set `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000` (30 sec)
3. set `validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"`

So what I'm trying to achieve is to make the server periodically ping unused connections (to keep them alive from Oracle's perspective) and if ping requests stopped coming in for more than 1 min Oracle should drop the session (and thus release locks).

Will it do the trick? Can you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: I'm curious why you are using "Select for update" across a session-pooled bit of middleware. It seems counter-intuitive, and generally goes against normal practices to hold a lock for the duration of your UI session..

Comment: I agree and it wasn't deliberately. SFUs come from a piece of 3rd-party code. They're generated by Hibernate in pessimistic lock mode.
I don't own that code but simply have to use it.
We're in the middle of transition to a clustered environment and recently I found those locked records.